# Xamarin Forms : advanced ContentView component with custom renderer

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I want to implement a kind of "user control" which contains 2 images. When i press on it, images sources are inverted. When i release, images are restored with original sources.
However, Xamarin tap gesture doesn't manage "pressed" state. So, i have decided to attach pressed and released gestures into the respective native components (Droid, iOS). I thought custom renderer could save me, but it doesn't work at all : in my Droid renderer, "Control" is null, so i can't attach Touch event. Any ideas ?

Here the code of my "user control" component :

**XAML**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ContentView xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms" xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml" x:Class="Xam_Test.Views.DoubleImageView">
    <ContentView.Content>
        <Grid>
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

            <Image Source="{Binding FirstImageSource}" Aspect="AspectFit" HeightRequest="{Binding ImageSize}"/>

            <Image Grid.Column="1" Margin="10,0,0,0" Source="{Binding SecondImageSource}" Aspect="AspectFit" HeightRequest="{Binding ImageSize}"/>
        </Grid>
    </ContentView.Content>
</ContentView>
```

**Code Behind**

```
public partial class DoubleImageView : ContentView
    {
        public static readonly BindableProperty FirstImageSourceProperty = BindableProperty.Create("FirstImageSource", typeof(string), typeof(DoubleImageView), string.Empty);
        public string FirstImageSource
        {
            set { SetValue(FirstImageSourceProperty, value); }
            get { return (string)GetValue(FirstImageSourceProperty); }
        }


        public static readonly BindableProperty ImageSizeProperty = BindableProperty.Create("ImageSize", typeof(int), typeof(DoubleImageView), 44);
        public int ImageSize
        {
            set { SetValue(ImageSizeProperty, value); }
            get { return (int)GetValue(ImageSizeProperty); }
        }


        public static readonly BindableProperty SecondImageSourceProperty = BindableProperty.Create("SecondImageSource", typeof(string), typeof(DoubleImageView), string.Empty);
        public string SecondImageSource
        {
            set { SetValue(SecondImageSourceProperty, value); }
            get { return (string)GetValue(SecondImageSourceProperty); }
        }


        public ICommand SwitchImageCommand { get; set; }

        public DoubleImageView()
        {
            BindingContext = this;
            SwitchImageCommand = new Command<bool>((bool isPressed) => UpdateImages(isPressed));
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void UpdateImages(bool isPressed)
        {
            string source;
            if (isPressed)
            {
                source = SecondImageSource;
                SecondImageSource = FirstImageSource;
                FirstImageSource = source;
            }
            else
            {
                source = FirstImageSource;
                FirstImageSource = SecondImageSource;
                SecondImageSource = source;
            }
        }
    }
```

**And here my Droid renderer**

```
[assembly: ExportRenderer(typeof(DoubleImageView), typeof(DoubleImageViewRenderer))]
namespace YourNameSpace.Droid.Renderers
{
    class DoubleImageViewRenderer : ViewRenderer
    {
        private ICommand _updateUICommand;

        protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
        {
            //MANAGE touch events
            if (_updateUICommand != null)
            {
                Control.Touch -= Image_Touch;
            }

            _updateUICommand = null;

            base.Dispose(disposing);
        }

        protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<Xamarin.Forms.View> e)
        {
            base.OnElementChanged(e);

            if (Control == null)
            {
                var view = (Context as Activity).LayoutInflater.Inflate(Resource.Layout.doubleimage, this, false);
                var firstImage = view.FindViewById<ImageView>(Resource.Id.first_imageView);
                var secondImage = view.FindViewById<ImageView>(Resource.Id.second_imageview);
                // ??????
                SetNativeControl(view);
            }

            if (Control != null)
            {
                DoubleImageView formView = (e.NewElement as DoubleImageView);

                ExtractFormData(formView);

                //MANAGE touch events
                if (_updateUICommand != null)
                {
                    Control.Touch += Image_Touch;
                }
            }
        }

        private void Image_Touch(object sender, TouchEventArgs e)
        {
            var handled = false;
            if (e.Event.Action == MotionEventActions.Down)
            {
                _updateUICommand.Execute(true);
                handled = true;
            }
            else if (e.Event.Action == MotionEventActions.Up)
            {
                _updateUICommand.Execute(false);

                handled = true;
            }

            e.Handled = handled;
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Extract form view data
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="formImage">form view object</param>
        private void ExtractFormData(DoubleImageView formView)
        {
            _updateUICommand = formView.SwitchImageCommand;
        }
    }
}
```

**EDIT**

Apparently, i have to create an android layout to manage the render of my custom component with SetNativeControl. Here my custom layout.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >
  <ImageView android:id="@+id/first_imageview"/>
  <ImageView android:id="@+id/second_imageview"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

I don't know how to bind my android layout with my form properties.

Answer (score 0):

If you derive from ViewRenderer your Control will be null. You have to set using SetNativeControl(view).

For iOS use

```
UIView view = new UIView();
view.Add(...)
SetNativeControl(view)
```

For Android if you have layout:

```
var view = (this.Context as Activity).LayoutInflater.Inflate(Resource.Layout.MyLayout, this, false);
SetNativeControl(view);
```

Comment: Could you give me some details ? Any tutorials to understand this part ? 

I am a beginner in Xamarin, and i am not and an android developer.
I have tried to a create a layout, which contains two ImageView like my form, with android:id to access them thanks to FindViewById (i suppose it's necessary).

However, how to map imageview components with my DoubleImageView properties ?

Comment: Please share you complete solution, I will take a look

Comment: I don't have more things than the content of my first post. 
i can add the content of my layout but it's ridiculous. 
I have tried to integrate your code, but i don't know how to do the magic for binding android and form data.

Comment: And this is why I asked for complete solution. Then I can quickly fix your code instead of spending time on creating the projects, your images, etc

Comment: The question was "in my Droid renderer, "Control" is null, so i can't attach Touch event" I showed you how to populate your Control. Now you are asking different question: "how to do the magic for binding android and form data" Please create a separate question or edit the question. If you want more help please provide complete solution

Comment: BTW, you don't even need custom renderer for what you do. You said: "Xamarin tap gesture doesn't manage "pressed" state". Keep states of the images in your page object and assign Source when image pressed. You can find how to add tap listener to image in stackoverflow answers or Xamarin docs

Answer (score 0):

it looks like you need to tell your ViewRenderer what it is actually rendering.  There are default renders such as EntryRenderer and ImageRenderer.  I have a custom tap gesture renderer and what I used was this...

```
ViewRenderer<GestureControl, Android.Widget.RelativeLayout>
```